# Ubuntu randomly goes to sleep after I have closed the lid of my latop(to put it to sleep)

Tags: 18.04, suspend, laptop

I am running Ubuntu 18 on a Razer blade Stealth 2017. I have it running side by side with windows 10.
I have experienced some issues with this and I have fixed all but one.

Whenever I want to put my laptop to sleep while using Linux, I would close the lid and it would go to sleep. Now when I come back, It would open and within 10 seconds it would go to sleep again, I then wake it up and log in and the process continues until I restart the system. This also happens if I just lock the screen for too long in my experience(without putting the lid down). This issue doesn't happen on windows so I doubt its a hardware problem.

I would love some help because the only workaround is to disable sleep mode.

When I run dmesg | grep sleep
i get a message that ACPI is preparing for sleep(S3), then that is it waking up.
This(the constant suspend problem) only happens after i manually suspend the system(by closing the lid).

Comment: Do you have a Nvidia Graphics? If so, have you installed the NVIDIA proprietary drivers?

Comment: No, I have Intel integrated.

Comment: What happens when you suspend using menu instead of closing lid. Then press power key to resume because lid is already open?

Comment: It does o the same thing no matter how i go into suspend. Once i suspend the system, it will randomly(very often) start suspends by itself. This lasts until i reboot the system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some more looking, I found this page
https://github.com/rolandguelle/razer-blade-stealth-linux/blob/master/ubuntu-18-10.md
It has many common bug fixes that have to do with the blade stealth.