# Ubuntu 18.04.3 Keeps Going To Sleep After I Re-Open Laptop

Tags: 18.04, laptop

So for a while I've wanted to switch over to Linux. I chose Ubuntu because I thought it would be really easy to transition from Windows. However, I've had a myriad of problems but the worst one is that if I close my laptop and then re-open  it, sign in, after about 10 seconds the laptop just goes back to sleep. This continues until I restart my laptop. I'm new to Linux but am comfortable navigating the terminal a bit. Any help is appreciated thank you.

Razer Blade Stealth,
Intel Graphics 620 Kaby Lake,
Intel® Core™ i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz × 4,
64-Bit 18.04.3

Comment: What is the make of the laptop? What is the model number printed on the serial number sticker? Are you on the charger when this happens, or off charger? Please click [edit] and add that to the original question; please don't use Add Comment, but instead use [edit].

Comment: Seems like they found a Solution: https://askubuntu.com/a/1122851/786777 Direct Link to Solution: https://github.com/rolandguelle/razer-blade-stealth-linux/blob/master/ubuntu-18-04.md#12-suspend-loop

Answer (score 2):

This Bug seens to be caused by a missing ACPI Signal for the "lid open event".

To fix this, add the following line to `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="button.lid_init_state=open"
```

and apply changes with

```
sudo update-grub
```

this worked for me.

I can highly recommend https://github.com/rolandguelle/razer-blade-stealth-linux
for futher issues with the Razer Blade Stealth Series and Ubuntu/Linux.

For further information about the `button.lid_init_state` Option see https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/9512307/